# How to edit HTML/CSS/Javascript in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, html, eclipse, cordova, web

I installed ADT bundle (eclipse + android sdk + adt plugin) now I want to build android apps with phonegap, the problem is that ADT eclipse doesn't include apparently any html/css/JS editor. I tried to install the WPA plugin but it doesn't work, it tells me it needs JSF (what the heck !?).

Is it normal that I can't find anything on that on the web ? Am I the only guy in the world using phonegap ? Is there another IDE I should use or which plugin can I install for web editing in eclipse ?

Comment: Do you have also Cordova instaled?

Comment: I had the same question, and found the [Amateras plugin](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=EclipseHTMLEditor).

Comment: I don't see why this question is off topic for SO... anyway to edit html/js/css files go to **preferences** -> **general** -> **editors** -> **File Associations** and change *.html *.js and *.css to use **text editor**

Comment: Once I also felt that I was the only guy using PhoneGap. Help here is very limited and outdated if any. There still seems to be two names for this project, i.e. phonegap and cordova, which confuses its learners even more, and its like this for years.

Comment: Salam, use from this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29206266/1676736

Answer (score 1):

File -> New -> Other -> Type html or javascript or css

Comment: well there is javascript, but not html nor css

Comment: Hmmm, seems strange. I have 'HTML File', 'CSS File' under Web node. You can also try to do this: File -> New -> File and give names with proper extensions: file.css for css, file.js for javascript or file.html for html. It works for me and eclipse 'knows' what kind of file it is and how to prompt properly. Ive checked it on two different versions of Eclipse on my computer right now. It just works.

Comment: the point is that it really doesn't know how to open html files : if i click on existing ones, it opens them in a sort of web view from IE. and i cant switch to editing mode, i can only open it as a text file.
Do you have Eclipse with plugin ADT or ADT bundle or another version ?

Comment: Try this: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/
or just instal new instance of Eclipse but version for Java EE Developers and then install ADT on it:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1

Comment: I didn't use Phonegap but I've heard about it. It seems that it has quite good and actual documentation (they claim that doc is the same version as dowloadable version): http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/index.html 
http://phonegap.com/download/