# How to open html file in editor using ADT Bundle for phonegap Apps

Tags: eclipse, cordova, adt

I had download and install ADT Bundle but the issue when i access the phonegap app workspace and try to open the html file it opens and webpage instead of editor can anyone tell how to open the html file in editor...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem and solve it with this solution:

1. Download last version of [Kepler - Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplersr2)
2. Open Eclipse and in Help => Install New Software...
3. In "Install" dialog, from "Work with:" select "--All Available Sites--"
   (for simple explore list, select all checkboxes in the bottom of dialog)
4. From loaded list select "Eclipse Web Developer Tools"
5. Press "Next" and finish to install checked item.
6. May need to Restart eclipse...

Now, your Eclipse ready to edit web files such as HTML, CSS and JavaScript, *but you can't create or manage Android projects!*

**Install ADT Plugins for Android developing** by these steps
([Download the ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download)):

1. Open "Install New Software..." dialog from Help menu in eclipse
2. Click Add button
3. In "Add Repository" dialog, add "ADT Plugin" for Name and paste this url for "Location":`https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
4. From "Work with:" list select "ADT Plugin"
5. From loaded list, select all items, press next and follow installation.
6. After restarting Eclipse you can import or create new Android project and edit web files also.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use `Java Editor`.

`Right click the html file-> open with -> other -> Java Editor`.

[image]

Comment: it opens the file but its like just opening a file as text file

Comment: @NeeravShah I updated my answer with screenshot. Please see if you have something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an HTML editor for Eclipse, take a look at [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) project.

The responses to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54868/1321873) have many more options.